# Why is the compiler able to vectorize the loop in my matrix-symmetrization function?

Tags: julia, llvm

The source code is in Julia, but my question is more about behavior of the LLVM compiler. I needed a utility function for symmetrizing an adjacency matrix (basically turning directed graph into undirected), and the baseline implementation is

```
function symmetrize!(A)

    m, n = size(A)
    @assert m == n

    @inbounds for i in 1:(n - 1)
        for j in (i + 1):n
            x = A[i, j] | A[j, i]  # symmetrize
            A[i, j] = x
            A[j, i] = x
        end
    end

end
```

The argument `A` is a matrix of zeros and ones, and the function symmetrizes it in place. The macro `@inbounds` is used to turn off bounds check. (In my case, it seems to make a difference to the compiler). In Julia, elements of a matrix are stored in **column-major order**. Out of curiosity, I checked the LLVM IR generated by the compiler, and to my surprise there are some basic blocks that use vector instructions:

```
vector.ph:                                        ; preds = %L43.preheader
  %n.vec = and i64 %25, -8
  %ind.end = add i64 %21, %n.vec
  br label %vector.body

vector.body:                                      ; preds = %vector.body, %vector.ph
  %index = phi i64 [ 0, %vector.ph ], [ %index.next, %vector.body ]
  %26 = add i64 %value_phi4, %index
  %27 = add i64 %23, %26
  %28 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %27
  %29 = bitcast i64* %28 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %29, align 8
  %30 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %28, i64 4
  %31 = bitcast i64* %30 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load29 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %31, align 8
  %32 = add i64 %26, %24
  %33 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %32
  %34 = bitcast i64* %33 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load30 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %34, align 8
  %35 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %33, i64 4
  %36 = bitcast i64* %35 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load31 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %36, align 8
  %37 = or <4 x i64> %wide.load30, %wide.load
  %38 = or <4 x i64> %wide.load31, %wide.load29
  store <4 x i64> %37, <4 x i64>* %29, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %38, <4 x i64>* %31, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %37, <4 x i64>* %34, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %38, <4 x i64>* %36, align 8
  %index.next = add nuw i64 %index, 8
  %39 = icmp eq i64 %index.next, %n.vec
  br i1 %39, label %middle.block, label %vector.body
```

I then checked the x64 assembly, and found that the compiler indeed emitted SIMD instructions. The portion corresponding to the basic block above is

```
.LBB0_8:                                # %vector.body
                                        #   Parent Loop BB0_4 Depth=1
                                        # =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
        vmovups -32(%rdx,%r9,8), %ymm0
        vmovups (%rdx,%r9,8), %ymm1
        vorps   -32(%rdi,%r9,8), %ymm0, %ymm0
        vorps   (%rdi,%r9,8), %ymm1, %ymm1
        vmovups %ymm0, -32(%rdi,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm1, (%rdi,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm0, -32(%rdx,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm1, (%rdx,%r9,8)
        addq    $8, %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %r10
        jne     .LBB0_8
```

Complete LLVM IR and x64 assembly are listed at the end.

**Question.** I'm not able to understand how the compiler is able to auto-vectorize the inner loop. It seems that the vectorized code overwrites 16 entries in one iteration. But why can we do so? Let's say we have an `N`-by-`N` matrix, where `N` is very large. When the induction variable `i` is equal to 1, the inner loop is supposed to symmetrize the pairs `(A[1, 2], A[2, 1])`, `(A[1, 3], A[3, 1])`, `(A[1, 4], A[4, 1])`, `(A[1, 5], A[5, 1])`, and so on, in the listed order. Because entries of the matrix are stored in column-major order, the elements `A[2, 1]`, `A[3, 1]`, `A[4, 1]` and `A[5, 1]` can be loaded by a single instruction, but elements `A[1, 2]`, `A[1, 3]`, `A[1, 4]`, `A[1, 5]` are located far apart in memory (with stride `N`), so how could we use vector instruction to load them?

Maybe I've completely misunderstood the LLVM IR/assembly, but I don't see how we could vectorize the inner loop of the matrix symmatrization function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Complete LLVM IR:

```
define void @"julia_symmetrize!_73"({}* noundef nonnull align 16 dereferenceable(40) %0) #0 {
top:
  %gcframe33 = alloca [3 x {}*], align 16
  %gcframe33.sub = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe33, i64 0, i64 0
  %1 = bitcast [3 x {}*]* %gcframe33 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i32(i8* noundef nonnull align 16 dereferenceable(24) %1, i8 0, i32 24, i1 false)
  %2 = call {}*** inttoptr (i64 140712069332416 to {}*** ()*)() #7
  %3 = bitcast [3 x {}*]* %gcframe33 to i64*
  store i64 4, i64* %3, align 16
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe33, i64 0, i64 1
  %5 = bitcast {}** %4 to {}***
  %6 = load {}**, {}*** %2, align 8
  store {}** %6, {}*** %5, align 8
  %7 = bitcast {}*** %2 to {}***
  store {}** %gcframe33.sub, {}*** %7, align 8
  %8 = bitcast {}* %0 to {}**
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds {}*, {}** %8, i64 3
  %10 = bitcast {}** %9 to i64*
  %11 = load i64, i64* %10, align 8
  %12 = getelementptr inbounds {}*, {}** %8, i64 4
  %13 = bitcast {}** %12 to i64*
  %14 = load i64, i64* %13, align 8
  %.not = icmp eq i64 %11, %14
  br i1 %.not, label %L5, label %L73

L5:                                               ; preds = %top
  %15 = add nsw i64 %11, -1
  %16 = icmp ult i64 %11, 2
  %17 = icmp eq i64 %15, 0
  %18 = select i1 %16, i1 true, i1 %17
  br i1 %18, label %L72, label %L23.preheader

L23.preheader:                                    ; preds = %L5
  %19 = bitcast {}* %0 to i64**
  %20 = load i64*, i64** %19, align 8
  br label %L23

L23:                                              ; preds = %L61, %L23.preheader
  %indvar = phi i64 [ 0, %L23.preheader ], [ %indvar.next, %L61 ]
  %value_phi4 = phi i64 [ 1, %L23.preheader ], [ %21, %L61 ]
  %21 = add i64 %value_phi4, 1
  %.not24 = icmp sgt i64 %21, %11
  %value_phi6 = select i1 %.not24, i64 %value_phi4, i64 %11
  %.not25 = icmp slt i64 %value_phi6, %21
  br i1 %.not25, label %L61, label %L43.preheader

L43.preheader:                                    ; preds = %L23
  %22 = xor i64 %indvar, -1
  %23 = add i64 %value_phi4, -1
  %24 = mul i64 %11, %23
  %25 = add i64 %value_phi6, %22
  %min.iters.check = icmp ugt i64 %25, 7
  %ident.check.not = icmp eq i64 %11, 1
  %or.cond = select i1 %min.iters.check, i1 %ident.check.not, i1 false
  br i1 %or.cond, label %vector.ph, label %scalar.ph

vector.ph:                                        ; preds = %L43.preheader
  %n.vec = and i64 %25, -8
  %ind.end = add i64 %21, %n.vec
  br label %vector.body

vector.body:                                      ; preds = %vector.body, %vector.ph
  %index = phi i64 [ 0, %vector.ph ], [ %index.next, %vector.body ]
  %26 = add i64 %value_phi4, %index
  %27 = add i64 %23, %26
  %28 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %27
  %29 = bitcast i64* %28 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %29, align 8
  %30 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %28, i64 4
  %31 = bitcast i64* %30 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load29 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %31, align 8
  %32 = add i64 %26, %24
  %33 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %32
  %34 = bitcast i64* %33 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load30 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %34, align 8
  %35 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %33, i64 4
  %36 = bitcast i64* %35 to <4 x i64>*
  %wide.load31 = load <4 x i64>, <4 x i64>* %36, align 8
  %37 = or <4 x i64> %wide.load30, %wide.load
  %38 = or <4 x i64> %wide.load31, %wide.load29
  store <4 x i64> %37, <4 x i64>* %29, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %38, <4 x i64>* %31, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %37, <4 x i64>* %34, align 8
  store <4 x i64> %38, <4 x i64>* %36, align 8
  %index.next = add nuw i64 %index, 8
  %39 = icmp eq i64 %index.next, %n.vec
  br i1 %39, label %middle.block, label %vector.body

middle.block:                                     ; preds = %vector.body
  %cmp.n = icmp eq i64 %25, %n.vec
  br i1 %cmp.n, label %L61, label %scalar.ph

scalar.ph:                                        ; preds = %middle.block, %L43.preheader
  %bc.resume.val = phi i64 [ %ind.end, %middle.block ], [ %21, %L43.preheader ]
  br label %L43

L43:                                              ; preds = %L43, %scalar.ph
  %value_phi10 = phi i64 [ %49, %L43 ], [ %bc.resume.val, %scalar.ph ]
  %40 = add i64 %value_phi10, -1
  %41 = mul i64 %40, %11
  %42 = add i64 %23, %41
  %43 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %42
  %44 = load i64, i64* %43, align 8
  %45 = add i64 %40, %24
  %46 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %20, i64 %45
  %47 = load i64, i64* %46, align 8
  %48 = or i64 %47, %44
  store i64 %48, i64* %43, align 8
  store i64 %48, i64* %46, align 8
  %.not26.not = icmp eq i64 %value_phi10, %value_phi6
  %49 = add i64 %value_phi10, 1
  br i1 %.not26.not, label %L61, label %L43

L61:                                              ; preds = %L43, %middle.block, %L23
  %.not27 = icmp eq i64 %value_phi4, %15
  %indvar.next = add i64 %indvar, 1
  br i1 %.not27, label %L72, label %L23

L72:                                              ; preds = %L61, %L5
  %50 = load {}*, {}** %4, align 8
  %51 = bitcast {}*** %2 to {}**
  store {}* %50, {}** %51, align 8
  ret void

L73:                                              ; preds = %top
  %52 = call [1 x {}*] @j_AssertionError_75({}* inttoptr (i64 2012767056112 to {}*)) #0
  %53 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe33, i64 0, i64 2
  %54 = extractvalue [1 x {}*] %52, 0
  store {}* %54, {}** %53, align 16
  %ptls_field34 = getelementptr inbounds {}**, {}*** %2, i64 2
  %55 = bitcast {}*** %ptls_field34 to i8**
  %ptls_load3536 = load i8*, i8** %55, align 8
  %56 = call noalias nonnull {}* @ijl_gc_pool_alloc(i8* %ptls_load3536, i32 1392, i32 16) #1
  %57 = bitcast {}* %56 to i64*
  %58 = getelementptr inbounds i64, i64* %57, i64 -1
  store atomic i64 140709931037936, i64* %58 unordered, align 8
  %59 = bitcast {}* %56 to {}**
  store {}* %54, {}** %59, align 8
  call void @ijl_throw({}* %56)
  unreachable
}
```

---

Complete x64 assembly:

```
        .text
        .file   "symmetrize!"
        .globl  "julia_symmetrize!_76"          # -- Begin function julia_symmetrize!_76
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_symmetrize!_76",@function
"julia_symmetrize!_76":                 # @"julia_symmetrize!_76"
        .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
        pushq   %r15
        pushq   %r14
        pushq   %r13
        pushq   %r12
        pushq   %rsi
        pushq   %rdi
        pushq   %rbx
        subq    $120, %rsp
        .cfi_offset %rbx, -72
        .cfi_offset %rdi, -64
        .cfi_offset %rsi, -56
        .cfi_offset %r12, -48
        .cfi_offset %r13, -40
        .cfi_offset %r14, -32
        .cfi_offset %r15, -24
        movq    %rcx, %rdi
        movabsq $140709931037936, %rsi          # imm = 0x7FF99574B4F0
        vxorps  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
        vmovaps %xmm0, -96(%rbp)
        movq    $0, -80(%rbp)
        leaq    2138294480(%rsi), %rax
        callq   *%rax
        movq    $4, -96(%rbp)
        movq    (%rax), %rcx
        movq    %rcx, -88(%rbp)
        leaq    -96(%rbp), %rcx
        movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)                 # 8-byte Spill
        movq    %rcx, (%rax)
        movq    24(%rdi), %r9
        cmpq    32(%rdi), %r9
        jne     .LBB0_14
# %bb.1:                                # %L5
        cmpq    $2, %r9
        jb      .LBB0_13
# %bb.2:                                # %L5
        movq    %r9, %r10
        decq    %r10
        je      .LBB0_13
# %bb.3:                                # %L23.preheader
        movq    (%rdi), %r15
        leaq    40(%r15), %rdx
        leaq    (,%r9,8), %r14
        leaq    8(,%r9,8), %rax
        movq    %rax, -128(%rbp)                # 8-byte Spill
        leaq    -8(%r15), %rbx
        movl    $1, %r12d
        movq    $-1, %r13
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        movq    %rdx, %rdi
        movq    %r10, -112(%rbp)                # 8-byte Spill
        movq    %r9, -104(%rbp)                 # 8-byte Spill
        jmp     .LBB0_4
        .p2align        4, 0x90
.LBB0_12:                               # %L61
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        incq    %r8
        addq    $16, %rdi
        addq    -128(%rbp), %rdx                # 8-byte Folded Reload
        decq    %r13
        addq    %r14, %rbx
        addq    $8, %r15
        cmpq    %r10, -136(%rbp)                # 8-byte Folded Reload
        je      .LBB0_13
.LBB0_4:                                # %L23
                                        # =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
                                        #     Child Loop BB0_8 Depth 2
                                        #     Child Loop BB0_11 Depth 2
        movq    %r12, %rax
        incq    %r12
        cmpq    %r9, %r12
        movq    %r9, %rcx
        movq    %rax, -136(%rbp)                # 8-byte Spill
        cmovgq  %rax, %rcx
        cmpq    %r12, %rcx
        jl      .LBB0_12
# %bb.5:                                # %L43.preheader
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        movq    %r8, %rax
        notq    %rax
        addq    %rcx, %rax
        movq    %r12, %r11
        cmpq    $8, %rax
        jb      .LBB0_10
# %bb.6:                                # %L43.preheader
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        movq    %r12, %r11
        cmpq    $1, %r9
        jne     .LBB0_10
# %bb.7:                                # %vector.ph
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        andq    $-8, %rsi
        movq    %rsi, -120(%rbp)                # 8-byte Spill
        leaq    (%r12,%rsi), %r11
        leaq    (%rcx,%r13), %r10
        andq    $-8, %r10
        xorl    %r9d, %r9d
        .p2align        4, 0x90
.LBB0_8:                                # %vector.body
                                        #   Parent Loop BB0_4 Depth=1
                                        # =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
        vmovups -32(%rdx,%r9,8), %ymm0
        vmovups (%rdx,%r9,8), %ymm1
        vorps   -32(%rdi,%r9,8), %ymm0, %ymm0
        vorps   (%rdi,%r9,8), %ymm1, %ymm1
        vmovups %ymm0, -32(%rdi,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm1, (%rdi,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm0, -32(%rdx,%r9,8)
        vmovups %ymm1, (%rdx,%r9,8)
        addq    $8, %r9
        cmpq    %r9, %r10
        jne     .LBB0_8
# %bb.9:                                # %middle.block
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        cmpq    -120(%rbp), %rax                # 8-byte Folded Reload
        movq    -104(%rbp), %r9                 # 8-byte Reload
        movq    -112(%rbp), %r10                # 8-byte Reload
        je      .LBB0_12
.LBB0_10:                               # %scalar.ph
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_4 Depth=1
        leaq    -1(%r11), %rax
        imulq   %r9, %rax
        leaq    (%r15,%rax,8), %rax
        incq    %rcx
        .p2align        4, 0x90
.LBB0_11:                               # %L43
                                        #   Parent Loop BB0_4 Depth=1
                                        # =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
        movq    (%rbx,%r11,8), %rsi
        orq     (%rax), %rsi
        movq    %rsi, (%rax)
        movq    %rsi, (%rbx,%r11,8)
        incq    %r11
        addq    %r14, %rax
        cmpq    %r11, %rcx
        jne     .LBB0_11
        jmp     .LBB0_12
.LBB0_13:                               # %L72
        movq    -88(%rbp), %rax
        movq    -64(%rbp), %rcx                 # 8-byte Reload
        movq    %rax, (%rcx)
        addq    $120, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rdi
        popq    %rsi
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r13
        popq    %r14
        popq    %r15
        popq    %rbp
        vzeroupper
        retq
.LBB0_14:                               # %L73
        movabsq $j_AssertionError_78, %rax
        movabsq $2012767056112, %rcx            # imm = 0x1D4A243F0F0
        callq   *%rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)
        movq    -64(%rbp), %rax                 # 8-byte Reload
        movq    16(%rax), %rcx
        movabsq $ijl_gc_pool_alloc, %rax
        movl    $1392, %edx                     # imm = 0x570
        movl    $16, %r8d
        callq   *%rax
        movq    %rsi, -8(%rax)
        movq    %rdi, (%rax)
        movabsq $ijl_throw, %rdx
        movq    %rax, %rcx
        callq   *%rdx
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_symmetrize!_76", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_symmetrize!_76"
        .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, the compiler ended up unrolling the innermost loop by a factor of 8, effectively introducing a third loop over blocks of your input matrix. This third loop can then be rerolled into vectorized accesses over a 4x4 block, where each column individually is adjacent data. You can sort of see this unrolling in the `vector.body`, where it ends up adding `8` the the loop index:

```
  %index.next = add nuw i64 %index, 8
```

On my machine with AVX512, this ends up unrolling even further:

```
[...]
vector.ph.new:                                    ; preds = %vector.ph
  %unroll_iter = and i64 %17, 2305843009213693944
  br label %vector.body

vector.body:                                      ; preds = %vector.body, %vector.ph.new
[...]
;  @ REPL[1]:10 within `symmetrize!`
; ┌ @ array.jl:1022 within `setindex!`
   store <8 x i64> %121, <8 x i64>* %118, align 8
   store <8 x i64> %122, <8 x i64>* %120, align 8
   %index.next.7 = add nuw i64 %index, 128
   %niter.next.7 = add i64 %niter, 8
   %niter.ncmp.7 = icmp eq i64 %niter.next.7, %unroll_iter
   br i1 %niter.ncmp.7, label %middle.block.unr-lcssa, label %vector.body
[...]
```

I don't know which Julia version you're running, but on mine (some very recent local build of the repo) the labels `%unroll_iter` and `%middle.block.unr-lcssa` persist, further suggesting this is due to loop unrolling (and subsequent rerolling).